# Intersection Point of Vector and line?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

**Problem:** Find the point at which the line through A(2,3,4) perpendicular to
the line y = -3x + 2 meets the line y = -3x + 2.

- This is taken from Herb Gross Multivariable
  Calculus course. While I do understand the solution that he provided (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/res-18-007-calculus-revisited-multivariable-calculus-fall-2011/cf5fa3544f6c9fe581780618d123db41_MITRES_18_007_partI_sol04.pdf)

*I don't understand why my working is wrong ?*

My thinking was I can have a vector that finished on point A and starting at O(0,0,0) hence vector A=(2i+3j+4k). Then take two points on the second line P1 and P2 and make a vector P2P1

P1 would be (0,2,0) and P2 would be generic point (x, 3x-2 ,0) P2P1= (x,3x-4,0)

Take the Dot product and since i know that they are perpendicular as stated the A·P2P1=0

We then have 2(x)+3(3x+4)+4(0)=0, isolate for x and then you can get y